# Why is my laptop goes to sleep every 1 minute?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hibernate

My windows-laptop goes into sleep mode if I don’t use a mouse or keyboard about 1 minute. Because I can’t read books.

I set all my power settings to 'NEVER SLEEP'. I disabled hibernate. I turned off my battery.
This not solved my problem, anyway.

I don't have this problem on xUbuntu, only windows. Reinstallations cannot solve this problem too.
Only if I watch videos my laptop didn't go to sleep.
btw I turned off my laptop monitor and connect via HDMI a new monitor.
Maybe this is the reason why it goes to sleep.

Comment: are you sure it's going to sleep mode, and not just a screen saver or the monitor turning off?

Comment: @user13267 yes I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is a second option to disable sleep (this will make sure you change your current power plan):

[image]